# How to use VBScript to open notepad and paste current date in it?

Tags: vbscript

How to use VBScript to open notepad and paste current date in it?

This is all I have for now:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Call WshShell.Run("%windir%\system32\notepad.exe")
Dim aDate
aDate = Date()
WScript.Sleep 2000
```

Now, how do I paste the date?

Comment: Did you google about your problem?

Comment: Yes, I did .. But couldn't find any solution

Comment: OK, I answered. It should work.

Comment: Sadly not working

Comment: Do you need to do it this way? Could you alternatively write the date to a text file then open the file with notepad ?

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you need the date in the text file for?

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`SendKeys`**](https://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html) to send keystrokes to the active window.

Usage:

```
WshShell.SendKeys aDate
```

You may need to ensure that the focus is in the window you want to send keystrokes to. For this, use [**`AppActivate`**](https://ss64.com/vb/appactivate.html) method.

Using window title in this case:

```
WshShell.AppActivate "Untitled - Notepad"
```

Comment: I tried using 
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
call WshShell.Run("%windir%\system32\notepad.exe")
Dim aDate
aDate = "Date()"
WScript.Sleep 4000
WshShell.AppActivate "Untitled - Notepad"
WshShell.SendKeys aDate                                     
and it sent me "Date" in Notepad

Comment: @DishantParakh then what happened? Isn't date printed?

Comment: no It didn't print the date. Instead it printed "Date"

Comment: @DishantParakh It is your fault. You are using `Date` function as a string literal! Use it without double quotes like `aDate = Date()` and post back the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
WshShell.SendKeys "{F5}"
```

Answer (score -1):

I know i am late, but try the following code, it works:

```
Set wshshell = wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Wshshell.run "Notepad"
wscript.sleep 100
dim aDate
aDate = Date()
wscript.sleep 2000
wshshell.sendkeys aDate
wscript.sleep 1000
```

Make sure the extension of the file is ".vbs"