# How to use VBScript to open notepad and paste current date with DDMMYYYY format in it?

Tags: vbscript

How to use VBScript to open notepad and paste current date in DDMMYYYY format?

When I use the below code, I get the output in DD/MM/YYYY format. I want it in DDMMYYYY format.

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

call WshShell.Run("%windir%\system32\notepad.exe")

Dim aDate

aDate = Date()

WScript.Sleep 4000

WshShell.SendKeys aDate
```

Could you guys please help me on this one?

Comment: Before asking a question, please do at least an small research.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use VBScript to open notepad and paste current date in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45341320/how-to-use-vbscript-to-open-notepad-and-paste-current-date-in-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format current date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574092/format-current-date-and-time)

Answer (score 0):

*The Date format you want:* **DDMMYYYY (without common slashes)**

This should work for you:

```
Dim WshShell: Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run("%windir%\system32\notepad.exe")
WScript.Sleep 4000

Dim aDate: aDate = WScript.CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder").AppendFormat("{0:dd}{0:MM}{0:yyyy}", Now).ToString()

WshShell.SendKeys aDate
```